# How to delete from table with composite primary key using a subquery

Tags: mysql

I need to delete lots of rows from a table with a composite primary key (ie - two fields together form the pk).

I identify the rows for the deletion with a query. But I'm not sure how to combine that query with the delete statement. This is what I tried:

```
DELETE FROM mytable 
WHERE (id1, id2) IN
(SELECT id1, id2 
  FROM (...a complex subquery to identify the lines I want to delete...) )
```

I ran this query on a copy of the database, but since we're talking  ~100,000 rows, I don't know how to make sure I'm deleting all the selected rows, and none of the other rows. I am certain the subquery yields the desired results, but I'm not sure if the syntax I used will delete these rows.

So my question is: does the `WHERE (id1,id2)` condition make sure I'm deleting the same rows selected in the subquery?

Thanks!

Comment: It is correct approach.